# Return a random word from a string using std::mt19937

Tags: c++, string, random

I want to use this algorithm for choosing a random word from a string:

Choose the first word with propability 1:1,

choose the second word with propability 1:2,

choose the nth word with propability 1:n

where each choice overwrites the last choice.

I want to use std::mt19937 for the "randomness". (is there a better method?)

My function should get an inputstring with this format:

```
word1 word2
word3 word4 word5
word6
```

where the number of words per line is unspecified, and words are seperated from eachother by blank spaces or new lines.

Is this the correct use of std::mt19937?

```
std::string random_word_from_string(std::string input)
{
    static auto gen = std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()};
    std::string random_word="";
    std::string word="";
    std::stringstream iss(input);
    auto count = 0u;
    while (iss >> word)
    {
        if (std::uniform_int_distribution{0u,count++}(gen) == 0)
        {
            random_word = word;
        }
    }
    return random_word;
}
```

If this question is already answered in c++, sorry, but I wasn't able to find it! But I am very thankful for getting a link to the duplicate.

Comment: Two questions for you: isn't 1:1 probability 100%? Or am I missing something here? And secondly, what have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a code writing service, but if you can show us your best attempt, we can help you get the code working. Can you read the strings in properly and store them in some kind of collection/container? Can you get one out randomly with a uniform distribution? Which part of this problem are you struggling with?

Comment: "Choose the first word with propability 1:1" this means you'll always just return the first word. That's certainly not what you want. Do you mean you'll choose each word with probability 1/n?

Comment: @John oh i clarify that, the first choice is indeed 100%, but gets overwritten by the next choice.

Comment: @SAJW that's equivalent to each word having 1/n probability.

Comment: @scohe001 I don't know how to do something with propability 1/n, that's where I am struggling

Comment: @SAJW That's the simplest case. It's also a uniform probability, it's exactly what the Mersenne Twister gives to you as is. For n words in input, each has a probability of 1/n to be chosen. But here words are a list, not a set, so if  word appear several times, it multiplies as many times its probability to be picked.

Answer (score 1):

[You can run the following program online:](https://wandbox.org/permlink/i5itoRLKoJO47QX8)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

std::string GetRandomString(int seed, const std::vector<std::string>& StrVector)
{
    std::mt19937 mt(seed);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 100.0);

    std::string ResultString= "";

    for(int i=0; i< (int) StrVector.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(dist(mt) < 100.0/(i+1))
            ResultString = StrVector[i];
    }

    return ResultString;
}

int main()
{ 
    std::vector<std::string> StrVector;

    StrVector.push_back("Hello");
    StrVector.push_back("my");
    StrVector.push_back("name");
    StrVector.push_back("is");
    StrVector.push_back("Bob");

    std::cout << GetRandomString(0, StrVector) << std::endl;
    std::cout << GetRandomString(1, StrVector) << std::endl;
    std::cout << GetRandomString(2, StrVector) << std::endl;
    std::cout << GetRandomString(3, StrVector) << std::endl;
    std::cout << GetRandomString(4, StrVector) << std::endl;  
}
```

The line

```
if(dist(mt) < 100.0/(i+1))
```

guarantees that the probability is chosen as you described.

The output reads:

```
Hello
name
Hello
name
my
```